# Next.js 13 getting hash and returning component on it

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

I'm noob in Next.js and React, but I'm trying to do something new.

How is possible now in Next.js 13.4 to get a #hash from an url using some hook instead of vanill `window.location.hash`?
I need to spy for the it's changing but I don't have any gueses about to do this now.

I've tried to use `useRouter` instead but in this version seems it's another new hook instead.

Now it's doesn't work, any chances to solve it?

**page.tsx:**

```
'use client'

import route from '@/config/routing'
import { Component1 } from '@/components/events_components/Component1'
import { Component2 } from '@/components/events_components/Component2'
import { Barlow } from 'next/font/google'

const barlow = Barlow({ subsets: ['latin'], weight: '900' })

export default function Home() {
    const hash: string = window.location.hash || route.modules.component1.hash

    const componentLoader = (hash: string) => {
        switch (hash) {
            case route.modules.component1.hash:
                return <Component1 />
            case route.modules.component2.hash:
                return <Component2 />
            default:
                return null
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="main__wrapper">
                    <h1 className={`${barlow.className} welcome__title`}>Lorem...</h1>
                    <p className={`${barlow.className} welcome__text`}>
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta placeat necessitatibus animi quam, ipsum minima possimus enim cumque nesciunt distinctio.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {componentLoader(hash)}
        </>
    )
}
```

I thought to use for it `useEffect` hook, but also to it I should to have another one variable to spy intead of hash.